# Compiling pintool with sqlite3 database

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking, dbi, intel-pin

I am writing a pintool to instrument my binary.

I would like to use sqlite3 database to store the information about instructions.

I can compile and execute sqlite3 "helloworld" example without any problem.
As well I can compile and execute my pintool without sqlite connection.
However, whenever I integrate sqlite code in the pintool I have an error:

> dlopen failed: library "libsqlite3.so.0" not found

What exactly I do:

1. My linking command looks like (compilation finishes without any error):

   > g++ -shared -Wl,--hash-style=sysv /home/roman/Software/pin/intel64/runtime/pincrt/crtbeginS.o -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script=/home/roman/Software/pin/source/include/pin/pintool.ver -fabi-version=2    -o obj-intel64/sqliteTest.so obj-intel64/sqliteTest.o  -L/home/roman/Software/pin/intel64/runtime/pincrt -L/home/roman/Software/pin/intel64/lib -L/home/roman/Software/pin/intel64/lib-ext -L/home/roman/Software/pin/extras/xed-intel64/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lpin -lxed /home/roman/Software/pin/intel64/runtime/pincrt/crtendS.o -lpin3dwarf  -ldl-dynamic -nostdlib -lstlport-dynamic -lm-dynamic -lc-dynamic -lsqlite3
2. LDD command ldd obj-intel64/sqliteTest.so gives me the following result:

> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4f4aa000)
>
> libxed.so => not found
>
> libpin3dwarf.so => not found
>
> libdl-dynamic.so => not found
>
> libstlport-dynamic.so => not found
>
> libc-dynamic.so => not found
>
> libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fd46221f000)
>
> libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd462002000)
>
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd461dfe000)
>
> libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd461a34000)
>
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055565d930000)

3. The symbol link ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite*:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1156080 Feb 22 17:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     965 Feb 22 17:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.la
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Feb 22 17:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Feb 22 17:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  870240 Feb 22 17:43 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6

4. The sqlite3 version is 3.13.0
5. When I run the pin tool I got the following:

> /home/roman/Software/pin/pin -t /home/roman/Software/pin/source/tools/sqliteTest/obj-intel64/sqliteTest.so -- ./test.bin
>
> E: Unable to load /home/roman/Software/pin/source/tools/sqliteTest/obj-intel64/sqliteTest.so: dlopen failed: library "libsqlite3.so.0" not found

6. In case you wonder about the code:

   ```
   VOID StartApp(VOID *v){

     int rc;
     char nameDB[100];

     sprintf(nameDB,  "pin_test_0.dat");

     rc = sqlite3_open(nameDB, &sqliteDB);

     if( rc ){
       fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(sqliteDB));
       return;
     }else{
       fprintf(stderr, "Opened database (%s) successfully\n", nameDB);
     }
     sqlite3_close(sqliteDB);

     //Start random number generator
     srand(rdtsc());
   }
   ...
   INT main(int argc, char *argv[]){

     if( PIN_Init(argc,argv) )
     {
       return Usage();
     }

     TRACE_AddInstrumentFunction(Trace, 0);

     PIN_AddApplicationStartFunction(StartApp, 0);

     PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

     PIN_StartProgram();

     return 0;
   }
   ```
7. When I put -Wl and --verbose options during the linking I got the following info:

> attempt to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so failed
>
> attempt to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a failed
>
> attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libsqlite3.so failed
>
> attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libsqlite3.a failed
>
> attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so succeeded
>
> -lsqlite3 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so)

Do you have any idea what is wrong with my hands?

Apparently pin v.3 has specific requirements for external libraries which I could not understand. I downgraded to pin v.2.8 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin changes the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when it starts, which may mean it won't find libsqlite in system directories. Pin 3 also avoids linking against certain system libraries to enhance isolation.

You shouldn't link against libpthread in either Pin 2 or Pin 3 or you're going to run into subtle bugs in the future. Sqlite seems to depend on libpthread. If you need to do something that requires a database, I recommend that you create an external process for that and communicate with it using named pipes/sockets.

Comment: Hello @nitzanms. Thank you for reply. Could you give any link where I might find information how to use sockets with pin3? This is not very obvious for me.

Comment: You have a point - you're probably better off simply writing to a file and having another program read that file for info.

Comment: Actually, I could recompile the sqlite3 with PinCRT so now sqlite3 can be integrated in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently pin v.3 has specific requirements for external libraries which I could not understand. I downgraded to pin v.2.8 and everything worked fine.